# What's the best way to save a RichTextFile in C#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, richtext, notepad, wordpad

I'm trying to create a notepad/wordpad clone. I want to save it in .rtf format so that it can be read by wordpad. How do I save a do this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do this yourself for learning purposes, you don't want to use a library to do it for you:

Basically you need to write a program which holds in memory either a string with RTF markup, or a DOM-like data tree. Using the [RTF specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277.aspx), you should write a flat (text) file marked up properly and with a .rtf extension. Just the same as if you were writing an HTML file.

Comment: Dude, your getting pretty close to 10K. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're using the RichTextBox control, you can just use the RichTextBox.SaveFile method to accomplush this. Just a guess though that you mean doing it without using that control.

Comment: I have to be honest with you, I didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RTF Spec[Link](http://www.informationweek.com/whitepaper/Windows-Microsoft/wp100287;jsessionid=G5QQV2HHI5ATQQSNDLRSKHSCJUNN2JVN?articleID=100287)

create the xml spec based on their api and you can make your app compatible with wordpad, word etc.